# Play audio files in C#

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

I need to play mp3 file. I want to use winmm.dll (Windows 7)

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string Cmd, StringBuilder StrReturn, int ReturnLength, IntPtr HwndCallback);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string FileName = @"F:\MUSIC\ROCK.mp3";

        string CommandString = "open " + "\"" + FileName + "\"" + " type mpegvideo alias Mp3File";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        CommandString = "play Mp3File";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

But when I run my program, nothing happened.
Where is a mistake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string FileName = @"F:\MUSIC\ROCK.mp3";
mciSendString("open \"" + FileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("play " + FileName + " from 0", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

It works correctly.

Comment: Are you the same Sergey who asked the question?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer will not work for file paths that contains spaces.  The correct method is to use the alias you set up in the open command:

```
string FileName = @"F:\MUSIC\ROCK.mp3";
mciSendString("open \"" + FileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias thisIsMyTag", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("play thisIsMyTag from 0", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your command string appears to have an incorrect type.

You're passing `type mpegvideo`, but the file is not a video file.

The correct type for audio is `type waveaudio` for *.wav files, `type sequencer` for *.mid files, `type cdaudio` for RedBook CD.  I don't see any way to play MP3 with MCI.  You could try leaving the `type` clause out entirely, then MCI will try to detect it.

Also, you should capture the error code returned by `mciSendString`, it may give you more information.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743638.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

**Here,**

```
class Program
{
  public string _command;
  public bool isOpen;
  [DllImport("winmm.dll")]

  public static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,StringBuilder strReturn,int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string FileName = @"F:\MUSIC\ROCK.mp3";
    string _command = "open \"" + sFileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
       mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
     isOpen = true;

     if(isOpen)
     {
        _command = "play MediaFile";
        if (loop)
         _command += " REPEAT";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
      }
/*For Close the audio
    _command = "close MediaFile";
    mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    isOpen = false; */
}
}
```

**CommandString should be "play Mediafile" instead of "play Mp3file" Hope It will help .. =]**

Comment: It needs to match the device ID used in the `alias` clause of the `open` command.  Which it already did in the original code.